# Can't make parabola without including the tip

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make an absolute value parabola function with TikZ. When I try to create the right and left sides of the parabola(the ones that would be underneath the x-axis in a normal function) I can't without including a bend underneath the x-axis.

```
\task\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-10,0)--(10,0);
    \draw(0,0) parabola bend(-3,6)(-6,0);
    \draw(0,0) parabola bend(-3,-6)(2,10);
    \draw(-6,0) parabola bend(-3,-6)(-8,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: This is what it looks like]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest solution is to draw two parabolas, one upside down, and clip them both to just show the parts above your line:

```latex
\documentclass[border=3.14,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (-5,0) rectangle (5,6);
      \draw (-4,6) parabola bend (0,-2) (4,6);
      \draw (-4,-6) parabola bend (0,2) (4,-6);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Approved always very simple solutions. Very good.

Answer (score 6):

Another simple solution is use the `plot` function and define parabola accordingly:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-5,0)--(5,0);
\draw[semithick, red] plot [domain=-2:2] (2*\x,{abs(\x*\x-1)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Or with declaring function in `tikzpicture` option and use 200 samples instead of default number (30, if I remember correctly):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function = {f(\x)={abs(\x*\x-1)};}
                        ]
\draw (-5,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[semithick, red] plot [domain=-2:2, samples=200] (2*\x,{f(\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This would be much slower, though, and it is dependent on the sample size (in your output one can see kinks in the parabola for instance). For stuff more complicated than `abs(x^2)` this would be the correct approach.

Answer (score 3):

This is really just for fun. You *can* make Ti*k*Z reflect the parabola (or anything you draw)  at the x axis (say) automatically. This can be done by installing a nonlinear transformation, which is in this case particularly simple.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\makeatletter
\def\yreflect{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{abs(\pgf@y)}%
    \pgf@y=\myy pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[transform shape nonlinear=true]
  \pgftransformnonlinear{\yreflect}
  \draw (-5,0)--(5,0);
  \draw (-4,6) parabola bend (0,-2) (4,6);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As one can see, there are small gaps, so the solution is not as perfect as [Skillmon's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508562/194703).

Comment: Please view the picture with 500/100,  I feel parabol doesn't cut Ox axis.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Yes, this is what is meant by "there are small gaps".